# Can't login via lightdm

Tags: login, xorg, kde, lightdm, xdmcp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 that is setup for remote logins via `XDMCP/LightDM`. Authentication is done via `LDAP/SSSD`. Everything works fine and users can login into KDE Plasma, except that for some users the session is immediately ended.

I checked the permissions on `.Xauthority` files - which are empty by the way, just like `.xsession-errors`.

The users that can not login via `LightDM` - can log in via terminal just fine. None of `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/lightdm` or `/var/log/auth.log` gives me any hints. AppArmor and SeLinux are disabled.

From `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: session-c79.scope: Killing process 26623 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: session-c79.scope: Killing process 26626 (lightdm-greeter) with signal SIGTERM.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: session-c79.scope: Killing process 26627 (lightdm-gtk-gre) with signal SIGTERM.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Session c79 of user lightdm.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Session c79 of user lightdm.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of XXX.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1406...
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Session c80 of user XXX.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Started Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Reached target Timers.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Reached target Paths.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Reached target Sockets.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Reached target Basic System.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Reached target Default.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Startup finished in 40ms.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1406.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu lightdm[25089]: Error activating login1 session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Operation not supported
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu systemd[26668]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Apr 29 14:05:26 desktop-ubuntu dbus-daemon[26706]: [session uid=1406 pid=26706] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213578)

Comment: @Marmayogi thanks for the hint, but did not fix the problem. These are the syslog files during the failing login attempt https://pastebin.com/vfawVtLM

Comment: Did you attach `/var/log/auth.log` details with pastebin?

Comment: @Marmayogi thanks for your support! https://pastebin.com/1n2PCxfU

Comment: You said that  `~/.Xauthority` file and `~/.xsession-errors` file were empty. Please check whether `HOME` directory is full with the command `df -h $HOME`.

Comment: There is a lot of free space and inodes. All ldap users can login via terminal - and some via lightdm. Removing the home directory and letting it being recreated from skel does not fix the issue. Newly created local users can login to the desktop. Letting lightdm run in debug mode leads to the following logs https://pastebin.com/rhd2aTmv - the difference between a failed login and a successful login is that the command "/usr/sbin/lightdm-session /usr/bin/startkde" seems to return an error. I could not find further informations using strace on lightdm.

Comment: It actually works after the first login on the physical desktop. Might be a problem with the .Xauthority file that does not get generated through Xvnc?

Comment: `/usr/bin/xauth` is the only command that can read `~/.Xauthority` file because this file is in `binary` form. Please issue the command `/usr/bin/xauth` and it will enter into `xauth>` prompt. Before entering into prompt, it will print `Using authority file /path/name/of/Xauthority` file. Please check that the file name is `$HOME/.Xauthority`. It may also point to either `/run/user/$(id -u)/lghtdm/Xauthority`, `/run/user/$(id -u)/gdm/Xauthority` or `/run/user/$(id -u)/kdm/Xauthority`. Please verify the value of `XAUTHORITY` by the command `echo $XAUTHORITY`. Please post the results.

Comment: You said in your post clearly that **AppArmor and SeLinux are disabled**. Whereas `/var/log/auth.log` that you posted above says that  `AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled` (refer the last line of the log). There seems to be a conflict. Please check.

Comment: @Marmayogi, looks like adding user-authority-in-system-dir=true to the LightDM config fixed the issue. Might be because user homes reside on nfs and users are able to log in to different desktops. Thanks for your support!